# Generate random number that changes every month

Tags: php, random

I need to generate a random number within a given range. The number **must be different for every new month of the year**, and it should not be the same (although theoretically it is possible) as the number generated the year before for that given month.

I was thinking of using the php `rand($min, $max)` function in conjunction with `date("w")`, I am struggling with the part where I need to get different results for every year.

To illustrate what I mean, check this:

```
$numbers = range(1, 100); //our random array
echo $numbers[date("w")]; //date("w") returns number of week
```

There are 2 problems here: 1) it is not really random, 2) the number will be the same every year and 3) it does not reflect the whole size of the array as date("w") returns a number between 1 and 52.

Do you think this is accomplishable in pure PHP? Or do I need to make a cronjob for this?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Couldn't you just store the random generated number, and every month generate a new one?

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I was wondering if there is a way without storing it. Maybe it's a little crazy tho ;)

Comment: Simple in principle: hash the value of `date('Ym')`. That gives you a random value for all intents and purposes which is uniquely linked to the current month. Hashes typically produce a hex or binary value, so you'll just have to base-convert it to decimal. To constrain it within a certain range, apply some operation like modulus.

Comment: I like the idea of hashing, could indeed be useful, thanks for that!

Comment: Could you generate a random number, select the closest multiple of 12, and then add the current month number?  For example, if the random number is 616, the closest multiple of 12 is 612.  Add 0 (since it's January) giving you a final answer of 612.

Comment: Thanks for that Steve, I think I will stick to the `srand($int)` method which seems more reliable.

Comment: @Adrenaxus No problem, but AFAICS currently neither answer will guarantee a unique number from month to month; setting the seed will only guarantee the same numbers.

Comment: If you want to *guarantee uniqueness*, you'll need to keep state somewhere. The given solutions are *unlikely enough* to generate duplicates.

Comment: I suppose a good solution could be to just store the previous numbers (in a database? this is php so I assume there's a database connection) and check the latest number against all previous numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use every month the same number in the seed. Just to be clear the seed in the function `srand ([ int $seed ] )`.

You can do something like this:

```
srand(100);
echo rand();
```

and every time it returns the same number. So every month you can do something like this:

```
$min = 1;
$max = 100;
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$seed = date('Ym'); // it is the date as an integer
srand($seed);
echo rand($min, $max);
```

Pay attention to set the default time zone. If you don't, the result will depend to the server configuration.

**-- UPDATE --**

As @StevenSmith and @axiac stated you're not 100% sure the random generated number is unique.
In other words this means that wider the range (min-max) higher the probability you'll have every time a different number.

Comment: Whoah that is some heavy stuff, interesting solution, will definetely check that out as well!

Comment: @freedev, Is setting the seed in this way guaranteed to give a unique number each month?

Comment: @SteveSmith Well, sorry, not unique. Random. This means that if the range is enough wide, you're are almost sure it returns a different number each time. While I wrote the answer I realised the difference.

Comment: @freedev Setting the seed will guarantee the same numbers, but AFAIK there's nothing to stop the same number coming up twice with different seeds.

Answer (score 1):

Use `date('Ym')` to generate an unique identifier for each (year, month) combination, use this value to initialize the pseudo-random generator's engine then generate one random number:

```
srand(date('Ym'));
$value = rand(1, 100);
```

Adjust the second line to match your needs. Now it generates an integer number between (and including) 1 and 100.

The value returned by `date('Ym')` is the same during a month. Every time you call [`srand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) with a certain argument, the pseudo-random generator is reinitialized using that value and then it produces the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers when [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) is invoked (several times).

This ensures the generation of the same value for you during the entire  month. During the next month and during the same month of the subsequent years the pseudo-random number generator is initialized with a different value and it generates a different sequence of pseudo-random numbers.

Depending on the values you use in your call to `rand()`, it might happen that the value returned by it this month is returned again in a different month. Use a large range for its [`$min`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) and [`$max`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) arguments to minimize this possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like both your and @freedev's solutions. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random number, select the closest multiple of 12, and then add the current month number.

For example, if the random number is 616, the closest multiple of 12 is 612. Add 0 (since it's currently January) giving you a final answer of 612.  This will ensure that the number is unique for each month.

Comment: This requires you to save that number somewhere, otherwise you won't be able to reuse it the entire month. If you're going to save numbers anywhere, there are simpler ways to ensure uniqueness.